# How is the ac load line for the following amplifier derived?

Tags: power, transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, ac

So I am trying to derive the ac load line for the following class A power amplifier
[image: Class A amplifier]

First I considered the reflected load/equivalent resistance of the transformer, this becomes 
$$R'_{L} = (\frac{n_{1}}{n_{2}})^2 R_{L}$$
This means the voltage drop across the equivalent resistance must be
$$i_{c}R'_{L}$$
So
$$V_{ce} = V_{cc} - i_{c}R'_{L}$$
However this is not the correct ac load line and I wanted to know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> This means the voltage drop across the equivalent resistance must be
>   \$i_{c}R′_{L}\$

No, you forgot that at DC, the transformer primary has a DC resistance of circa 0 ohms and this is in parallel with \$R'_L\$.

For AC signals of sufficient frequency that the primary inductance can be ignored (i.e. is much bigger in magnitude than \$R'_L\$), the AC signal at the collector is basically swinging symmetrically around \$+V_{CC}\$.

In other words a signal at the collector can swing from nearly 0 volts to +20 volts when \$+V_{CC}\$ is 10 volts: -

[image]

Picture taken from [this slide show, page 16](https://www.slideshare.net/sarahkrystelle/power-amplifiers-11169136).

Comment: Why do you say that at DC we have 0 ohms in parallel to R'L? At DC there is no R'L, or R'L=0 (basically the transformer is not working). Am I missing something?

Comment: @SredniVashtar a real transformer can be modelled as a perfect impedance transformer in parallel with its primary magnetization inductance hence, at DC that magnetization inductance has a reactance of zero ohms but, is still in parallel with the projected impedance from the secondary. The net result is of course still zero ohms.

Comment: Thanks. So, very loosely speaking, we can say that the concept of nonzero (reflected) impedance has a meaning even at DC because  the infinite inductance of the ideal transformer is 'compensating' for the zero frequency of DC? I hate ideal components, they create unreal situations...

Comment: Infinite magnetization inductance is probably unresolvable as an impedance at DC so, it’s difficult to answer but, who cares!!! If you need a DC Amplifier, don’t use a transformer.

Comment: @Andyaka Why is the collector voltage able to reach 2Vcc?

Comment: Because, the transformer primary magnetization inductance stores energy when the collector is trying to force itself down towards 0 volts. That energy remains inside the magnetic field while ever the collector current is greater than the quiescent current. As collector current returns (cyclically) to its quiescent value, the energy begins to be released from the inductor and, the primary voltage (aka collector voltage) has to rise above Vcc to accommodate. Or, think of it another way.... the long term average voltage across an inductor has to be zero. It’s not easy to grasp I understand that.

Answer (score 0):

DC doesn't cause substantial voltage drop in the transformer, if it's properly designed. In idle state the voltage between the collector of the transistor and GND is =Vcc or more precisely Vcc - Ico x Rt where Ico is the idle state collector current and Rt is the resistance of the transformer primary.

The signal makes Ic swing around Ico. Voltage between the collector and GND swing around the idle value with amplitude Is x Rr where the Is is the signal current amplitude and Rr is your reflected load resistance. This is applicable if the signal is inside the usable frequency range of the transformer. It's essential to notice that the voltage at the collector can be momentarily more than the supply voltage Vcc.

The operation of the transistor needs that Vce is at least few hundred millivolts positive. Thus the signal voltage swing at the collector cannot be larger than the idle state voltage between the collector and emitter. Also Re causes some drop but if we can consider Ico x Re small the theoretical upper limit for the momentary voltage at the collector is 2Vcc.

Reliable operating point to prevent the thermal rush generally forces us to sacrifice at least few hundred millivolts as Ico x Re, so in practice we can approximate the maximum momentary voltage between the collector and GND to be 2Vcc-1V. The maximum momentary Vce is a little less, say 2Vcc-1,5V due the drop in Re, which is kept stable with a massive capacitor CE to prevent gain loss.

The whole circuit is very old fashioned. It's a class A single transistor output stage. It was widely used in walkie-talkies and cheap battery radios 50...65 years ago if the budget or the available space didn't allow a push-pull amp.

Circuit theorists would say we got the numerical relations by using the superposition principle. We calculated separately for DC and signal and added the resulted voltages and the resulted currents to get the total voltage and the total current.

Comment: Why would this result in a maxiumum voltagae of 2Vcc?

Comment: @cojoye  because the DC Q point is Vcc

Comment: Another question I'd like to ask is why is the bias point at Vcc in a transformer coupled class A amplifier but the bias point is Vcc/2 in a regular class A amplifier?

Comment: The tansformer doesn't cause substantial voltage drop at DC, Vcc - 0 =Vcc. Resistor betwee collector and the plus supply drops voltage at DC. One want's in both cases to maximize the non-clipping voltage swing range. Let's put the clip happen at the plus and minus peaks in the same time when the current swings sinusoidally.